# Why does the label element have a form attribute?

Tags: html, forms

In the HTML standard, why does the HTML `label` element have a [`form`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html#label.attrs.form) attribute defined for it when it already has the `for` attribute? What purpose does it have?

If I have a label element where either the child contents are an input type or the `for` attribute is used what purpose does the `form` attribute have?

For example, in each of the `label` scenarios below the 'owning form' is known by either looking at the children or the parent elements. Is there another scenario where a `label` with a `form` attribute would be both useful and not increase clutter?

```
<body>
<form action="#" id="form-one" method="post">
    <label>Dog name<input type="text" id="tb-dog-name"></label>
    <button type="submit" id="form-one-submit">Post Dog Name</button>
</form>

<form action="#" id="form-two" method="post">
    <label for="tb-cat-name">Cat name</label>
    <input type="text" id="text-box-two">
    <button type="submit" id="form-two-submit">Post Cat Name</button>
</form>

<label for="tb-pizza">How much do you like pizza?</label>
<input type="text" id="tb-pizza" form="form-three">
<form action="#" id="form-three" method="post">
    <button type="submit" id="form-three-submit">Share your love!</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: @j08691 http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html#label.attrs.form I have no idea what it's for...

Comment: @WesleyMurch - Ah new in HTML5.

Comment: I mean, I took 2 seconds to Google it: http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/

Comment: @WesleyMurch — That discusses the form attribute for form controls (like input), not labels.

Comment: @Quentin Ah yes I see. It seems really sketchy to be honest, would never use. Seems like a good way to get in to trouble when you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) states:

> **form** (HTML5) The form element that the label element is associated with
>   (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be an ID of a 
>   element in the same document. If this attribute is not specified, this
>    element must be a descendant of a  element. **This
>   attribute enables you to place label elements anywhere within a
>   document, not just as descendants of their form elements.**

[Additionally](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fae-form): A form-associated element (button fieldset input keygen label object output select textarea img) is, by default, associated with its nearest ancestor form element (as described below), but, if it is reassociateable (button fieldset input keygen label object output select textarea), may have a form attribute specified to override this.

Comment: I still don't really get the practical purpose. Can you think of any? I guess just edge cases? It's a weird one.

Comment: Seems like it frees the label element up to appear anywhere in the DOM, and not stuck as a descendant of a form. Useful? Meh.

Comment: Yeah very much Meh. Interesting though. Still not sure how it makes sense, as `for` should be unique anyways right? I mean, there shouldn't be two elements with the same id (value of `for`).

Comment: But isn't this the purpose of the for attribute?

Comment: I still don't see why this isn't achieved by setting `for="id_of_input_in_some_other_form"`. Why would the label be associated with a form other then the one to which its form control belongs to?

Comment: I believe the `for` attribute for a label is a reference to the form element associated with that label, whereas the `form` attribute indicates which form in the DOM the label (or other form element) belongs to.  So if I have two forms on a page, I can arrange the two submit buttons outside of the forms if I so desire, as long as the `form` attribute for each button references the form for which they submit.